# Use pg textsearch with multiple conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Im currently using postgres textsearch functionality to search recipes which have a particular ingredient like so

```
Recipe.includes("ingredients").where("ingredients.name @@ :query", :query => query)
```

but what i want to do is to be able to search for multiple ingredient query names, either matching all or any depending on the situation.

I.e. given these two recipes and their ingredients

Sandwich => Bacon, cheese, tomato
Pasta    => Bacon, Olive

using these custom methods id like to define

Recipe.search_by_any("Bacon Tomato") => Sandwich and Pasta
Recipe.search_by_all("Bacon Tomato") => Sandwich

How do you achieve this using pg textsearch on associated record columns?

### I dont want to use PGSearch gem as it's giving me some wierd errors

Answer (score 1):

Partial answer:

The easy search is the one which matches any ingredient. Use an inner join to filter the results you want.

```
def self.search_by_any(query)
  ingredients_query = query.split(' ').join('|')  # Convert queries like "Bacon Tomatoes" to "Bacon|Tomatoes"

  Recipe.joins(:ingredients).includes(:ingredients).where("ingredients.name @@ to_tsquery(:ingredients_query)", :ingredients_query => ingredients_query)
end
```

The search_by_all method is going to be a bit more complicated. I'll take a look at it later if no one else has given a good suggestion.

Answer (score -2):

In most of this cases I would like to use the PgSearch gem (https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search). I think you could find the multi-search method helpful in this case.

Comment: What would be an example of multi-search method for this case?